# Translating German Jewish birth record in Hebrew

Tags: germany, birth-records, jewish, 1830s, hebrew

Can somebody translate the two lines in Hebrew of this birth record for a German Jew from 1832 in Dessau?

The German part is translated (s. below), what is missing is the line in Hebrew in the first column and the penultimate word in the second column.

[image]

After some commenting, the German text reads:
"Geburt | Am 11 Febr.(uar 1832) kam die (missing given name, most likely of a femal person) Löser (Patronym) Reichenheim mit einem unehelichen Sohne nieder welcher \ den Namen Abraham (hebrew) erhielt."

Rough English translation:
"Birth | On the 11th of February the ... Löser Reichenheim gave birth to an illegitimate son (...) who \ received the name Abraham (hebrew)."

Here is the entire page as requested for comparable reading with the entry in question, fifth entry from above.

[image]

Comment: Small detail: The word after "Sohne" is "nieder" and belongs to "kam" (from niederkommen, as in Niederkunft, that is, delivery of the child). The translation would change to "delivered the (...) a illegitimate son".

Comment: The Hebrew in the left box might just be a note, and not related to the birth date. Are there other Jewish birth entries in the same records to compare what typical components of the entry are?

Comment: Thank you, jadepx, for your input. I updated the original post accordingly. I will add the entire page as you requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not precisely answers your question, but I believe helps somehow (could not render it as a comment).

I singled out in red the hebrew texts I could notice.
[image]

Let's split them into 2 groups:

1. to the left of the vertical double-line separator
2. to the right of this same separator

I believe the beginning of the text in group (1) denotes the date (year). However, I would expect 1832 to render `תקצ"ב` (try [this](https://www.hebcal.com/converter)) - but the text does not look like that. Isn't the word in german there (the one beginning with Ge****) related to date/time ?
<strike>The last word in the hebrew text in group (1) reads "Avra" I would think it corresponds to the Abraham I see in the right. But again the hebrew I would expect should be `אברהם` or at least `אברם`, and again it does not match.</strike> (See **updated** section).

The hebrew word (is it hebrew ? it looks like...) in group (2) - I can't decipher at all. **Update:** there is a chance this is Avraham (which Abraham translates from), in this particular cursive writing script. I can see the right parenthesis, then an *alef*, a *bet* with a leg that stretches to the succeeding *reish*, then a heh then a *mem sofit*.

Try [JewishGen's ViewMate](https://www.jewishgen.org/viewmate/) - I used them a lot a decade ago, I assume they are just as helpful.

**Update:**
Great you shared the whole document. Now I can go over other entries in the same column, and now I can say the hebrew in what I called group (1) is indeed the date. In your case I am still unsure about the year, but the rest indicates it was on the month of Adar Alef (1st month of Adar (it was a Hebrew leap year (does not coincide with Gregorian leap years), when a 2nd month of Adar is added, meaning a year has 2 Adar months, denoted as Alef (1st) and Bet (2nd))

Comment: Thank you very much, Veverke, for your help. I've just added the translation of the German text to my original post. This may help.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Hebrew script, but group (2) looks more like Latin characters to me (unless it's some form of cursive). Maybe an abbreviation, or an additional identifier for the person? (Quite clueless here)

Comment: @jadepx: may be. I had the feeling it was cursive Hebrew indeed.

Comment: @TilHund: great you shared the original full document. See the updated section in my answer. This adds an additional small piece to the puzzle.